# I have Database file(,sql) and I would like to use this database file in phonegap

Tags: sql, cordova

I have Database file(.sql) and I would like to use this database file in phonegap. how can i do ? 
sql file can work with phonegap ?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Check out a couple of my blog posts on the subject:

Creating a DB from a SQL file:
http://simonmacdonald.blogspot.ca/2011/12/on-fourth-day-of-phonegapping-creating.html

Copying an existing SQLite DB file:
http://simonmacdonald.blogspot.ca/2011/12/on-second-day-of-phonegapping-copying.html